# Is Anathem a version of Plato's Republic?

Tags: greek-language, plato, neal-stephenson, anathem

Is Neal Stephenson's novel *Anathem* a version of Plato's *Republic*?
Those who have read the novel and have a little Plato will understand why I ask. We often point to [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Swift) as the originator of modern speculative fiction, but Plato introduced a mythology of [Atlantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis) as an allegory.  Plato's philosophy comes to us mainly in the form of [narrative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato#Dialogues), a form definitely inspired by the "dialogue" within Greek drama in Plato's time, [Libation Bearers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oresteia#The_Libation_Bearers)/[Elektra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electra_(Sophocles_play))/[Elektra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electra_(Euripides_play)) as an example.

Comment: I never read *Anathem*, but Rand's *Anthem* is actually a version of Plato's *Republic*. Is there a connection there? An important character in the former is named "Durand"...

Comment: @user13861 I don't know Rands work that well, but it must be a reference since Stephenson has a moderately libertarian viewpoint.  Wordplay is definitely an element in the title and book.